# Example apps using Renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

I want to learn more about Renderscript. What are the apps out there that is using Renderscript? I want to see real apps in the market, instead of some tutorial examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout ImageProcessingJB app in Android-L source code. It's:

- Renderscript app
- Open source, you can play around, make changes, build the app locally and run it on the device.
- Covers most of the Api's that renderscript provides.

PS: Source code can be found under `frameworks/rs/java/tests/ImageProcessing_jb` folder of Android-L source tree.

Answer (score 0):

so far I know is live wallpaper, google claim has book and youtube, but I didn't find script code in youtube